# My import for kafka is not working my spring boot version is 2.7.18

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-boot-maven-plugin, spring-boot-starter

I tried 2.8x to 2.9x but my import for kafka is not working

these imports they are unable to find after kafka plugin

`org.springframework.kafka spring-kafka 2.8.0`

just tell me the version to go with ?

`import org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory; import org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory; import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;`

these are the imports

`<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId> <version>2.7.18</version>`

Answer (score 0):

try this : works fine with springboot 2.7.16

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.9</version>

    </dependency>
```